# How do I make an certain command repeat over and over again?

Tags: python, loops, cmd, administrator

I've got an python bot. It needs too much memory and that results in it crashing. Sometimes It just crashes randomly...

My problem is that I need to re-type my commandline to make it re-start again.

Is there any way to write a self-looping command line? like it should loop the last line I typed in manually again and re-start.

If it crashes it looks like this: "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/newbot>"

That above is print out if it crashes, since I'm running the .py bot on Windows 10 through cmd (opened as administrator).

Someone please help me out making a auto-repeating command line that re-enters this "roblox roblox.py" and presses enter everytime it crashses!

I can't figure it out myself, I've got zero python experience, it would be really nice of you guys, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean it crashes ? your bot raise an exception ? or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this in a Batch (.bat) file and run it

```
:loop
roblox roblox.py
goto loop
```

[You could have found this with a little search](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001050.htm)

Comment: You are looking for the `pause` command. Write it on its own line where you need it.